# ts-loader, antd and, typescript - cannot find module index.less

Tags: typescript, webpack, antd

In my project I am using [antd](https://ant.design/components/layout/) react component library and I need to use [ts-loader](https://github.com/Brooooooklyn/ts-import-plugin) to load the components in a reasonable fashion. Right now I am trying to wrestle webpack to transpile [less](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) files but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
...
```

It looks like either the less-loader is not installed(it is) or it's not configured correctly(it should be). Here's my webpack config:

webpack.dev.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
      },
    ]
  },
```

common.webpack.js

```
const getTsLoaderRule = env => {
  const rules = [
    { loader: 'cache-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            getCustomTransformers: () => ({
            before: [ tsImportPluginFactory({
              libraryDirectory: 'es',
              libraryName: 'antd',
              style: 'css',
            })]
          }),
          compilerOptions: {
            module: 'es2015'
          }
        },
    }
  ];
  if (env === 'development') {
    rules.unshift({
      loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack'
    });
  }
  return rules;
};
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: getTsLoaderRule(options.env),
        include: [utils.root('./src/main/webapp/app')],
        exclude: ['node_modules']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=content/[hash].[ext]']
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loaders: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: ['node_modules']
      }
    ]
  },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not about a misconfigured `less-loader` but rather a missing `less`, which is a peer dependency of the package. Run `npm i -S less` to install it.

Comment: It's installed. What else could it be?

Comment: I’m not sure, then, as it specifically mentions `less`. Is it possible for you to put together a minimal repository on GitHub to test it out? What does your index.less look like?